# What is the sum of the digits of the number 2^1000?

Tags: c#, arbitrary-precision

This is a [problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=16) from [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/), and this question includes some source code, so consider this your spoiler alert, in case you are interested in solving it yourself. It is discouraged to distribute solutions to the problems, and that isn't what I want. I just need a little nudge and guidance in the right direction, in good faith.

The problem reads as follows:

> 2^15 = 32768 and the sum of its digits is 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26.
>
> What is the sum of the digits of the number 2^1000?

I understand the premise and math of the problem, but I've only started practicing C# a week ago, so my programming is shaky at best.

I know that int, long and double are hopelessly inadequate for holding the 300+ (base 10) digits of 2^1000 precisely, so some strategy is needed. My strategy was to set a calculation which gets the digits one by one, and hope that the compiler could figure out how to calculate each digit without some error like overflow:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace euler016
{
    class DigitSum
    {
        // sum all the (base 10) digits of 2^powerOfTwo
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int powerOfTwo = 1000;
            int sum = 0;

            // iterate through each (base 10) digit of 2^powerOfTwo, from right to left
            for (int digit = 0; Math.Pow(10, digit) < Math.Pow(2, powerOfTwo); digit++)
            {
                // add next rightmost digit to sum
                sum += (int)((Math.Pow(2, powerOfTwo) / Math.Pow(10, digit) % 10));
            }
            // write output to console, and save solution to clipboard
            Console.Write("Power of two: {0} Sum of digits: {1}\n", powerOfTwo, sum);
            Clipboard.SetText(sum.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Answer copied to clipboard. Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work perfectly for powerOfTwo < 34. My calculator ran out of significant digits above that, so I couldn't test higher powers. But tracing the program, it looks like no overflow is occurring: the number of digits calculated gradually increases as powerOfTwo = 1000 increases, and the sum of digits also (on average) increases with increasing powerOfTwo.

For the actual calculation I am supposed to perform, I get the output:

> Power of two: 1000 Sum of digits: 1189

But 1189 isn't the right answer. What is wrong with my program? I am open to any and all constructive criticisms.

Comment: See if BigInteger can help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

Comment: @luiges90, woah, was not aware of that. I will give it a try.

Comment: the sum is obviously 1 (if you are using base 2)

Comment: The flaw in your program is that you very quickly run into precision errors; doubles are only accurate to about 15 decimal places and you need 300 to get the correct answer. Use BigInteger, as others have said. You might want to read my ongoing series of articles on how to implement your own large integer library; by early next week there will be enough code available to solve your problem, though since the algorithms are recursive, 2^1000 will blow the stack.  Start here: http://ericlippert.com/2013/09/16/math-from-scratch-part-one/

Comment: Think about it like this: obviously to accurately represent numbers on the 2^1000 you need on the order of 1000 bits. A double has 64.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks I'll have a look, I arrived at that conclusion after I realized Math.Pow is not some magic wand that psychically knows the precision I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normal [`int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w(v=vs.90).aspx) can't help you with such a large number. Not even [`long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx). They are never designed to handle numbers such huge. `int` can store around 10 digits (exact max: `2,147,483,647`) and `long` for around 19 digits (exact max: `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`). However, A quick calculation from built-in Windows calculator tells me `2^1000` is a number of more than 300 digits.

(side note: the exact value can be obtained from `int.MAX_VALUE` and `long.MAX_VALUE` respectively)

As you want precise sum of digits, even [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) or [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) types won't work because they only store significant digits for few to some tens of digits. (`7` digit for float, `15-16` digits for double). [Read here for more information about floating point representation, double precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision)

However, C# provides a built-in arithmetic 
[`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) for arbitrary precision, which should suit your (testing) needs. i.e. can do arithmetic in any number of digits (Theoretically of course. In practice it is limited by memory of your physical machine really, and takes time too depending on your CPU power)

---

Back to your code, I think the problem is here

`Math.Pow(2, powerOfTwo)`

This overflows the calculation. Well, not really, but it is the `double` precision is not precisely representing the actual value of the result, as I said.

Comment: Haha! Yes, I got the correct answer by using BigInteger. I figured out your last paragraph in the middle of reading my own question. Math.Pow gives a double, so both terms in that equation are not precisely representing what they are intended to.

Comment: In fact, I recommend you to study the math behind and try not to use `BigInteger` :) unfortunately I threw those math away already :(

Comment: You're right, BigInteger is almost cheating. What a powerful secret weapon it is though. I think it can greatly simplify many of the Project Euler solutions, although it may not be optimal, or educational.

Comment: @trav1s just don't do programming but little mathematics can help save your computation and of course so many CPU cycles

Comment: This may not be the most efficient solution, but I am accepting it because it was what I was looking for: It indicates the problem with my program, and shows how it can be fixed. It doesn't provide source code outright. Finally, the resulting program has very low run time, about 1 ms on my modest machine. I am sure there are some choice mathematical nuggets that could be extracted by doing it differently, but I am satisfied doing it this way.

Comment: @trav1s we are here to help you and provide solution best to our knowledge and experience and it is right too that you accept the answer what you think has solved your problem (+1 for that).

Comment: 2^10 ≈ 10^3 so each 10 bits corresponds to about 3 decimal digits, or simply count 3 bits for each digit, that leaves you ~1000/3 digits in decimal

Answer (score 13):

For calculating the values of such big numbers you not only need to be a good programmer but also a good mathematician. Here is a hint for you,
there's familiar formula a<sup>x</sup> = e<sup>x ln a</sup> , or if you prefer, a<sup>x</sup> = 10<sup>x log a</sup>.

More specific to your problem 
2<sup>1000</sup> Find the common (base 10) log of 2, and multiply it by 1000; this is the power of 10. If you get something like 10<sup>53.142</sup> (53.142 = log 2 value * 1000) - which you most likely will - then that is 10<sup>53</sup> x 10<sup>0.142</sup>; just evaluate 10<sup>0.142</sup> and you will get a number between 1 and 10; and multiply that by 10<sup>53</sup>, But this 10<sup>53</sup> will not be useful as 53 zero sum will be zero only.

For log calculation in C#

```
Math.Log(num, base);
```

For more accuracy you can use, Log and Pow function of Big Integer.

Now rest programming help I believe you can have from your side.

Comment: I have been trying to understand this but I don't get it yet. So 2^1000 = 10^(1000 * log_10 (2)). Okay, with you so far. Then "you get something like 10^53.142" how? I got 10^301.0299957... and I think the decimal would still exceed the double type.

Comment: @trav1s 53.142 is just example not actual value of log 2

Comment: @trav1s there is log and power function for BigInetgers too and I am sure you can be precise only upto that values

Comment: And then round to the nearest integer I guess. This should be more memory efficient than calculating the entire number at once. Not sure if it can really save CPU cycles as you claim though with so many log calculations...

Comment: @trav1s why we need to round to nearest integer, at last you need sum of all the variables and you can loop to each value by casting the BigInt to string and yes there will be CPU cycles saved.

Answer (score 2):

A solution without using the BigInteger class is to store each digit in it's own int and then do the multiplication manually.

```
static void Problem16()
{
    int[] digits = new int[350];

    //we're doing multiplication so start with a value of 1
    digits[0] = 1;
    //2^1000 so we'll be multiplying 1000 times
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        //run down the entire array multiplying each digit by 2
        for (int j = digits.Length - 2; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            //multiply
            digits[j] *= 2;
            //carry
            digits[j + 1] += digits[j] / 10;
            //reduce
            digits[j] %= 10;
        }
    }

    //now just collect the result
    long result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.Length; i++)
    {
        result += digits[i];
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used bitwise shifting to left. Then converting to array and summing its elements. My end result is 1366, Do not forget to add reference to System.Numerics;

```
BigInteger i = 1;
         i = i << 1000;
        char[] myBigInt = i.ToString().ToCharArray();
        long sum = long.Parse(myBigInt[0].ToString());
        for (int a = 0; a < myBigInt.Length - 1; a++)
        {
            sum += long.Parse(myBigInt[a + 1].ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

since the question is c# specific using a bigInt might do the job. in java and python too it works but in languages like c and c++ where the facility is not available you have to take a array and do multiplication. take a big digit in array and multiply it with 2. that would be simple and will help in improving your logical skill. and coming to project Euler. there is a problem in which you have to find 100! you might want to apply the same logic for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using BigInteger `type` , 2^100 will end up to a  a very large number for even double to handle.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger bi= new BigInteger("2"); 
bi=bi.pow(1000); 
// System.out.println("Val:"+bi.toString()); 
String stringArr[]=bi.toString().split(""); 
int sum=0; 
for (String string : stringArr) 
{ if(!string.isEmpty()) sum+=Integer.parseInt(string); } 
System.out.println("Sum:"+sum);
------------------------------------------------------------------------
output :=> Sum:1366
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution in *JavaScript*

```js
(function (exponent) {
  const num = BigInt(Math.pow(2, exponent))
  let arr = num.toString().split('')
  arr.slice(arr.length - 1)
  const result = arr.reduce((r,c)=> parseInt(r)+parseInt(c))
  console.log(result)
})(1000)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a serious answer—just an observation.

Although it is a good challenge to try to beat Project Euler using only one programming language, I believe the site aims to further the horizons of all programmers who attempt it. In other words, consider using a different programming language.

A Common Lisp [solution](http://ideone.com/0V9xwD) to the problem could be as simple as

```
(defun sum_digits (x)
    (if (= x 0)
        0
        (+ (mod x 10) (sum_digits (truncate (/ x 10))))))

(print (sum_digits (expt 2 1000)))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 main()
 {
   char c[60];
  int k=0;
     while(k<=59)
      {
    c[k]='0';
   k++;

    }
       c[59]='2';
       int n=1;
     while(n<=999)
       {
       k=0;
     while(k<=59)
      {
        c[k]=(c[k]*2)-48;
        k++;
      } 
    k=0;
     while(k<=59)
        {
        if(c[k]>57){ c[k-1]+=1;c[k]-=10;   }
       k++;
         }
       if(c[0]>57)
        {
         k=0;
         while(k<=59)
           {
         c[k]=c[k]/2;
          k++;
           }
           printf("%s",c);
             exit(0);
           }

            n++;
            }
          printf("%s",c);
              }
```

Comment: If you add description to your answer, that will help a lot

Answer (score -1):

Python makes it very simple to compute this with an oneliner:

```
print sum(int(digit) for digit in str(2**1000))
```

or alternatively with map:

```
print sum(map(int,str(2**1000)))
```