# Getting the value of 2^1000

Tags: c#, math

Ok so currently using Math.Pow I'm getting this. `1.07150860718627E+301`.
How can I get the precise value of that some 300 digit value. I'm doing a project euler problem, but I guess maybe this is part of the problem.

Comment: I'd try looking into the BigInteger class.

Comment: Or, if memory serves me, you could only consider the important digits because that's probably what the problem is about.

Comment: I don't think the point of that problem is to actually compute 2^1000.

Comment: The problem wants the sum of the digits of that number. Once I can get the correct value of the number I'll be able to solve it.

Comment: @Jon I think that computing it is the easiest way to solve [the problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=16).

Comment: I agree with @Jon The real exercise is to find a way without using big integers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the sum of the digits of the number 2^1000?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310133/what-is-the-sum-of-the-digits-of-the-number-21000)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.Numerics.BigInteger` (available in .NET 4.0 and higher).

You can read more about BigInt [here](http://www.carljohansen.co.uk/bigint/).

You can also use some third-party libraries.

If you use a different version of .Net framework you could use e.g.:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class
2. http://ironpython.codeplex.com/

Comment: It's in System.Numerics.dll ([see the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx))

Answer (score 2):

this will work

```
System.Numerics.BigInteger.Pow( new System.Numerics.BigInteger( 2 ), 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will give you the value of 2^n. Here is the code given below.

```
private static BigInteger findPower(int n) {
    BigInteger [] arr = new BigInteger[n+1];
    arr[0]= BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        
        arr[i] = arr[i-1].multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
        
        
    }
    
    return arr[n];
    
}
```

Similarly, you can modify this function for any any base to any power.