# sum of the digits of the number 2^1000 in java

Tags: java

```
import java.math.*;

public class PowerDigitSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] digits ;
        digits = new double[302];
        double i = Math.pow(2, 1000);
        double c = 301;
        double c1 = 0;
        double d = 0;
        while(c>=0) {
            c1 = Math.pow(10, c);
            d = Math.floor(i/c1);
            i = i - d*c1;
            digits[(int)c] = (int)d;
            c = c-1;
        }
        double sum = 0;
        c = 0;
        while (c<302) {
            sum = sum+digits[(int)c];
            c= c+1;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

The output is 1281 but that's not correct according to projecteuler. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't do correct math with double values that large due to their limited nature. Use BigDecimal, or in your case BigInteger is sufficient.

Comment: @deHaar, why? It's not like that's a hard number to compute, you just need about 1000 bits to store it (use uint1000, if you will), set the most significant bit to 1 and the rest to 0 and there you go.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov it's too big for simple data types... Storing them in bits will of course do... But correct: The comment was unqualified.

Comment: `String.valueOf(BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(1000)).chars().map(i -> i - 48).sum()`... Just another way of doing it.

Comment: @ernest_k More readable: `BigInteger.TWO.pow(1000).toString().chars().map(c -> c - '0').sum()`

Comment: print the digits you are summing and you will see that soon (after about 20 digits) you'll get only zeroes.

Comment: @Andreas, I'd still prefer `Character::getNumericValue`.

Comment: @Andreas Agreed, more readable (Didn't know about `TWO` - another java9 addition)

Comment: Thread on Code Review about the same question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/228838/project-euler-16-sum-of-all-digits-of-21000

Answer (score 0):

You can't do correct math with double values that large due to their limited nature.

You could probably fix your code with `BigDecimal`, but it is much easier using `BigInteger`. Hint: it has a `pow` method, and you can work out the digit sum starting from `toString`.

Comment: I don't know what the goal of Project Euler is, but is using a BigInteger library cheating?

Comment: Accepted answer over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19310209/14955 also uses BigInteger, so ...